# Error during dynamic form creation from json Cannot find control with name: 'data'

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am using angular 7 appplication and i am writing a generic dynamic form creator. I am using reactive forms and `ng-template and   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet>` for recursively displaying the form element.The code of the project could be seen [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztx4cp).

But i am facing the following error

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'data'
    at _throwError (forms.js:1775)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:1683)
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:4532)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5030)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:4980)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9239)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10507)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10469)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11102)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11062)
```

But if i see my formGroup object i can see a control with data as the name of the control as shown below.

[image]

What is the mistake i am doing ? Please help.

Reproduction of the problem is [Here stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztx4cp)

Comment: From the information provided, it looks like the `data` form control has not been created when you try to access it. If you want a more complete answer, you need to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I have already attached the stackblitz link in the question. The formgrouo is initiatialized fine. Seems like a problem with ng-template. Pleaee have a look at the stackblitz

Comment: Which structure of object do you want to post to server? Like this `{
  "CartName": null,
  "CartType": null,
  "CartSerialNumber": null,
  "CartDate": {
    "data": null
  },
  "DrawersPresent": [
    {
      "CartDate": {
        "data": null
      }
    },
    {
      "Drawer2": null
    },
    {
      "Drawer3": null
    },
    {
      "Drawer4": null
    }
  ]
}`? I ask it because you don't generate FormGroup correctly in your code

Comment: Its a configurable data basically. The array could be either object array, or a primitive array (string/number). Thats why if he specifies type as 'simple', the resultant will be ['123','123','123'], if object [{},{},{}]. But i guess the below example you showed doesn't satisfy this i guess. Anyway i can fix that myself without worry. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right there is a problem with ng-template here.

`FormControlName` directive heavily relies on hierarhy of elements above current element to determine `FormControl`.
Since you're using `ngTemplateOutlet` this hierarhy mixed up and Angular can't find parent `FormGroup` or `FormArray` controls.

You can refactor your example to use nested components and it should work if you will keep hierarhy of child `AbstractControls`.

On the other hand, you can make it work with `ngTemplateOutlet` if you will use [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) directive.
You need to only make sure you provided correct control to your `input` element.

Here's how it could be done:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="controlList; context: {controls: schema, path: []}"></ng-container>

    <ng-template #controlList let-controls="controls" let-path="path" let-isArray="isArray">

        <ng-container *ngFor="let control of controls; let i = index;">
            <ng-container *ngIf="control?.type === 'simple'">
                <div class="control">
                    <label>
              {{ control.label }}
              <input type="text" [formControl]="form.get(isArray ? path.concat(i, control.name) : path.concat(control.name))"> 
            </label>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="['object', 'array'].indexOf(control.type) > -1">
                <fieldset>
          <legend>{{control.name}}</legend>
                    <ng-container
                        *ngTemplateOutlet="controlList; context: {controls: control.items, isArray: control.type === 'array', path: isArray ? path.concat(i, control.name) : path.concat(control.name)}">
                    </ng-container>
                </fieldset>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>

    </ng-template>
</form>
```

The key point here is to get correct `path` to destination control which I'm passing as part of context to next child level.

Also if you want to generate infinity structure nested elements you should refactor your code for building FormGroup:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.schema = data.start.fields.schema;
  this.form = this.createFormGroup(this.schema);
} 

createFormGroup(items) {
  let group: { [controlId: string]: AbstractControl; } = {};

  items.forEach((item) => group[item.name] = this.createFormControl(item));

  return this.fb.group(group);
}

createFormControl(item) {
  if (item.type === 'array') {
    return this.fb.array(item.items.map((subItem) => {
      return this.fb.group({
        [subItem.name]: this.createFormControl(subItem)
      })
    }));
  } else if (item.type === 'object') {
    return this.createFormGroup(item.items);
  } else {
    return this.fb.control(item.value, []);
  }
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/7NL4D98BzqugLEgECbnU?open=app%2Faddcart.ts&layout=1)**

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Just need to clarify few things before i accept the answer. How much performance efficient is form.get(isArray ? path.concat(i, control.name) . Won't it be called for every ngDoCheck cycle ?

Comment: Also can you explain whats happening here path: isArray ? path.concat(i, control.name) : path.concat(control.name). What is this path variable used for ? Bit of explanation would help me understand it better. Hope its not too much to ask.

Comment: Yes, it will be called on every ngDoCheck cycle. But actually Angular does the same thing with formControlName internally

Comment: `path: isArray ? path.concat(i, control.name) : path.concat(control.name)` Here I define `path` variable by using ternary operator. In simple words: if it's an array then I add index(`i`) and `name` to the current `path` otherwise I add only `name`. So say we have `path` equal to `['someName']` if it's an array then I need to pass `[someName', index, 'someOtherName']` otherwise `['someName', 'someOtherName']`

Comment: I know the ternary operator. I meant the intend of using the path variable. Anyways it going through the code it makes sense. Understood :)

Comment: Hi. On a second thought, if i want to send data to server as an array of strings ["D1","D2","D3"], would it be possible with the above approach ? I am not able to figure out how. If possible could you please update the ng-run to show how.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the formcontrol is unable to decide the parent, that's why console error is appearing and sometimes the value entered is also not correctly mapped, So the Solution that worked for is putting

```
<form [formGroup]="control">
</form>
```

inside the div which has [formGroupName]="index"

So it will look like

```
<div *ngFor="let control of recursiveForm.get('controlList')['controls']; let index = index" [formGroupName]= "index">

<form [formGroup]="control">
<input type="text" formControlName="name">
</form>
</div>
```